# setting ui slider values programmatically

Tags: ios, uislider

I am working from a template project and I now have to add a uislider, I want to be able to programatically program the values from my ui slider from a class that is already set up called Price delegate. 
When I'm researching this I keep coming back with JQuery? can I only do it using jQuery?

I need the closed to read in from the price delegate here is my minimum slider code

```
- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender {

    UISlider *slide = (UISlider *)sender;
    int min = (int)(slide.value);
    //Display min price
    NSString *minprice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", min];

    NSLog(@"min : %@",minprice);

    label_min.text = minprice;


    NSString * priceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",
                              [priceDelegate.values objectAtIndex: [_appDelegate int_minPriceV]]];


    [self.tf_price setText:priceString];
}
```

and here is the values I would like the slider to read from

```
-(void) loadData{
    NSArray* array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                      NSLocalizedString(@"No Min", nil), 
                      @"50,000",
                      @"100,000",
                      @"150,000",
                      @"200,000",
                      @"250,000",
                      @"300,000",
                      @"350,000",
                      @"400,000",
                      @"450,000",
                      @"500,000",
                      @"550,000",
                      @"600,000",
                      @"650,000",
                      @"700,000",
                      @"750,000",
                      @"800,000",
                      @"850,000",
                      @"900,000",
                      @"950,000",
                      @"1,000,000",
                      @"1,250,000",
                      @"1,500,000",
                      @"1,750,000",
                      @"2,000,000",
                      @"3,000,000",
                      @"4,000,000",
                      nil];

    self.values = array;
    [array release];
```

How to do it or what way to head?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Jquery, do you just want to know how to programatically set values from your delegate class?

Comment: Thankyou, and yes, but when i research it all query stuff comes up? @JohnWoods

Comment: All you have to do is call setValue or use the .value property to set the slider, is this not working for you? can you link to the pages suggesting to use jquery?

Comment: I will see if i can find them as I've been researching a few bits, and thanks i will try that. @JohnWoods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple once you know what to do. Set your slider's range to be from 0.0 to 1.0 (the default).

Now your slider action method becomes:

```
- (IBAction)slider:(UISlider *)slider {
    CGFloat value = slider.value;
    NSUInteger index = value * (self.values.count - 1);
    NSString *priceString = self.values[index];

    // Do what you need with priceString
}
```

Comment: omg thank you so so so much!! this worked perfectly!! i would up vote your answer but i don't have the reputation credit yet! THANK YOU!